# Customize external URLs in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to build a .NET site with MVC and have some external links on it. These URLs I don't want to show directly, but through customized ones.

For example: instead of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996673/lower-case-urls-in-asp-net-mvc, just only http://example.com/link/1234.

I know in PHP man can do it with .htaccess and a php file but I'm not sure it's possible in ASP.NET. Someone has suggested me to do it with .cshtml but I don't know how.

Can someone please help me to clear this question?

Thanks.

---

*Updated:*

Thanks for all your tipps. After reading the 2 pages on codeproject.com you suggested, I just think that these are useful only for internal URLs, for external they seem to be complicated.

I would think that for each external one I will have one URL: http://example.com/link/1234 and then when clicked it will link with one View 1234.cshtml. This cshtml file should then redirect to the actual link (I don't know as it's possible with Razor).

So I believe there must be a simpler way to get the job done. So anyone else 
has other ideas, please share! Thanks!

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996483/Tutorial-creating-a-URL-shortener-using-ASP-NET-We

Comment: or this http://anderly.com/2010/06/10/create-your-own-branded-url-shortener-in-under-10-minutes-using-asp-net-mv2/

Answer (score 0):

In route.config file you can construct your url as the way you want.

Comment: please go thru this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624181/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: or this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HttpResponse.RedirectLocation Property** in a controller to achieve this. For detail use this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectlocation(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Response.RedirectLocation = string.Format("http://bit.ly/{0}", linkid));
return new View();
```